# Data is submitted to database but not displaying with foreach() in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

i hope you are doing good.
i'am new to laravel and i searched a lot but no chance.

So i hava a form it contain fields to submit a comment here is the code :

```
<!-- comment -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="margin-top-35"></div>
        <div class="utf-inner-blog-section-title">
            <h4><i class="icon-line-awesome-comments-o"></i> Laisse votre commentaire</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-top-15"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="prop_id" id="prop_id" value="{{ $proprety->id }}">
        <div id="add-comment">
            <form class="add-comment" action="/commentannonce" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="prop_id" value="{{ $proprety->id }}">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Nom Complet*" value="" name="nom"
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Adresse Email  *" value="" name="email"
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="tel" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone *" value=""
                                name="telephone" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Sujet" value="" name="sujet"
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <textarea cols="30" placeholder="Commentaire..." rows="2" name="commentaire" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="utf-centered-button">
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit Comment</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <!-- comment -->
```

when i submit this form it store in the database normally.

here is my model for the comment

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Annoncecomment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'prop_id',
        'nom',
        'telephone',
        'email',
        'sujet',
        'commentaire',
    ];
}
```

and this is my controller for the comment :

```
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request){
        $form_data = array(
            'prop_id' =>   $request->prop_id,
            'nom'  =>$request->nom,
            'telephone' => $request->telephone,
            'sujet'=>$request->sujet,
            'email' =>$request->email,
            'commentaire'=>$request->commentaire,
        );
        $commentaire = Annoncecomment::create($form_data);
        $user = User::first();
        $commentaire = Annoncecomment::where('prop_id',$request->prop_id)->count();
        $commentaires = Annoncecomment::where('prop_id',$request->prop_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $user = User::first();
        return redirect('/proprety/'.$request->prop_id)->with([ 'commentaire'=>$commentaire, 'commentaires'=>$commentaires]);




    }
```

So now i need to display these comments on a property page so i added code to property controller and i made it like this where $commentaires and commentaire are my variables one who get count and seconde to display.

```
$commentaire = Annoncecomment::where('prop_id',$proprety)->count();
        $commentaires = Annoncecomment::where('prop_id',$proprety)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $rate =  DB::table('clients')
        ->join('ratings', 'ratings.client', '=', 'clients.id')
        ->where('ratings.client',$proprety->client)->sum('star_rating');
        $rateC =  DB::table('clients')
        ->join('ratings', 'ratings.client', '=', 'clients.id')
        ->where('ratings.client',$proprety->client)->count();
        if($rateC == 0){
            $rate = 0;
        }else{
            $rate = $rate/$rateC;
        }


        return view('client.propretry.showProprety')->with(["commentaire"=>$commentaire, "commentaires"=>$commentaires,"rate"=>$rate,'cat'=>$cat,'area'=>$area,'price'=>$price,'type'=>$type,'client'=>$client,'similair'=>$similar,'image'=>$image,"states"=>$state,"proprety"=>$proprety]);
```

Back to the view of the property page i made a foreach but it dont display data and there is NO error or something in the console i made my for each like this :

```
section class="comments">
                    <div class="utf-inner-blog-section-title">
                        <h4><i class="icon-line-awesome-commenting-o"></i> Commentaires ({{ $commentaire->count() }})</h4>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($commentaires as $i)
                            <li>
                                <div class="avatar"><img src="/assets/media/avatars/blank.png" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="comment-content">
                                    <div class="arrow-comment"></div>
                                    <div class="comment-by">{{ $i->nom }}
                                        <span class="date">{{ date('F j, Y', strtotime($i->created_at)) }}</span>
                                        @if (Auth::user())
                                            <a href="#" data-id="{{ $i->id }}" id="replay"
                                                class="reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Répondre</a>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <p>{{ $i->commentaire }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <ul>
```

What i did wrong ?

I know this is a little bit long but i'am struggling for 5 hours now.

Thank you very much

UPDATE UPDATE :
when i change this, from property controller it display all the comment but not the specifique comment for the prop :

```
this :$commentaires = Annoncecomment::where('prop_id',$proprety)->get();
to this : $commentaires = Annoncecomment::all();
```

Comment: could you double check what is the value of `$proprety` and check if there are records in this table with the same value of `prop_id`

Comment: $proprety is displaying all the column of the its table except the id this is its value :   0 => "unique"
    1 => "client"
    2 => "title"
    3 => "photo"
    4 => "status"
    5 => "type"
    6 => "price"
    7 => "unit"
    8 => "area"
    9 => "room"
    10 => "adr"
    11 => "state"
    12 => "commune"
    13 => "desc"
    14 => "other"
    15 => "sps"
    16 => "pay"
    17 => "floor"
    18 => "nbrFloor"
    19 => "etat"
    20 => "payPar"
    21 => "expire"  //// the record prop_id is in the Annoncecomment table

Comment: this is the problem `$proprety` is not an integer it is an array

Comment: i'am a begginer , so i'am trying to understand more , how i process to the solution? thank you

Comment: the `$property` value should be an `integer`

Comment: but it must be an array ,  i convert it?

Comment: if you want to pass `array` of **ID's** so you need to edit it like this `->wherIn('prop_id', [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: thank you for your answer , i tried it but same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the data in view method as second parameter not in with;

```
return view('client.propretry.showProprety', ["commentaire"=>$commentaire, "commentaires"=>$commentaires,"rate"=>$rate,'cat'=>$cat,'area'=>$area,'price'=>$price,'type'=>$type,'client'=>$client,'similair'=>$similar,'image'=>$image,"states"=>$state,"proprety"=>$proprety]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didint work